# Filtro na minha tabela criada com NGFor

Tags: angular, filter, rowfilter

Criei uma tabela com NgFor (na verdade, todo meu projeto usa como padrão estruturas ngFor), vi que existe um NgRepeat e existe um filtro para a mesma. Por fins de evitar migrar meu projeto de ngFor, existe alguma maneira de filtrar minha table?

Eu usaria um campo de texto e o valor digitado seria filtrado (pode ser tanto por campo específico como generalista)

Já tentei usar PipeTransform, porém sem sucesso.

Html:

```
<div>
<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope = "col">PID            </th>
        <th scope = "col">CODIGO        </th>
        <th scope = "col">CLIENTE       </th>
        <th scope = "col">SIGLA_RM      </th>
        <th scope = "col">SIGLA_PORTAL  </th>
        <th scope = "col">COMERCIAL     </th>
        <th scope = "col">ATENDIMENTO   </th>
        <th scope = "col">AUDITORIA     </th>
        <th scope = "col">PERIODICIDADE </th>
        <th scope = "col">ENTREGA       </th>
        <th scope = "col">RESPONSAVEL   </th>
        <th scope = "col">Comando       </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

<tbody>

<tr *ngFor = 'let planilha of planilha '>
      <td>
        {{planilha.ID}}
      </td>
      <td>
          {{planilha.CODIGO}}
      </td>
      <td>
          {{planilha.CLIENTE}}
      </td>
      <td>
          {{planilha.SIGLA_RM}}
      </td>

      <td>
          {{planilha.SIGLA_PORTAL}}
      </td>

      <td>
          {{planilha.AUDITORIA}}
      </td>

      <td>
          {{planilha.PERIODICIDADE}}
      </td>

      <td>
          {{planilha.ENTREGA}}
      </td>
      <td>
          {{planilha.RESPONSAVEL}}
      </td>
      <td>
          {{planilha.LAYOUT}}
      </td>

      <td>
          {{planilha.ODS}}
      </td>
      <td scope = "col">
        <img src="assets/Detalhes.png" [routerLink]="['/detalhes/',planilha.PID]" width="25px"/>
        <img src="assets/excluir.png" (click)="deletaProd(planilha.PID)" width="25px"/>
      </td>

</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Typescript:

```
import { Component, OnInit,Input, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-planilhaweb',
  templateUrl: './planilhaweb.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./planilhaweb.component.css']
})
export class PlanilhawebComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  @Input('planilha') public planilha
  public xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  public detalhes: boolean = true
  public detalhesId: number

  constructor() { 
    this.dao();
  }


  ngOnDestroy(){

  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

   public deletaProd(id){
    function reqListener () {
      console.log('tentou excluir ',id)

    };

    var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
    oReq.onload = reqListener;
    oReq.open("DELETE", "http://localhost:51230/api/logs/deletar/plan/"+id+"", true);
    oReq.send();
    this.dao();
    this.load();
  }


  public detalhesProd(id){
    this.detalhesId = id;
    this.detalhes = !this.detalhes;
    console.log(this.detalhesId)
  }

  dao(){
//CONEXAO COM A API
async function getPlanilha()
{
  const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:51230/api/logs/producao/plan/`);
  return await response.json();
}

//promisses
getPlanilha()
  .then((planilha) => this.planilha = planilha)
}

load() {
  //Session storage salva os dados como string

  (sessionStorage.refresh == 'true' || !sessionStorage.refresh) && location.reload();
  sessionStorage.refresh = true;

}


}
```

**Atualização:**

[image: exemplo]

Consegui filtrar o meu vetor (json), porém a tabela não altera dinamicamente acompanhando o filtro, como isso deve ser feito?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creio que essa resposta vai te ajudar

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52739260/add-search-filter-to-angular-6-datatable

***Apenas descrevendo a resolução da resposta acima***

Apenas crie uma array que vai conter os dados da array **planilha** (Exemplo **planilhaFilter**), porém filtrados, **e ela que será usada no ngFor** e sempre que você digitar algo no campo de texto, ele vai chamar uma função para atualizar a array criada (**planilhaFilter**) a partir da array **planilha**.

Exemplo:

```
<input type="text" (keyup)='filtrar($event.target.value)'>
```

E no seu arquivo .ts

```
filtrar(value: string) {
   if(!value) {
      this.planilhaFilter = this.planilha;
   } else {
     this.planilhaFilter = this.planilha.filter(x => 
        x.CLIENTE.trim().toLowerCase().includes(value.trim().toLowerCase())
     );
   }
}
```

**EDITADO**

Se voce esta requisitando alguma API apos os dados serem filtrados e quer mostrar apenas de acordo com o filtro, voce pode **criar uma variavel para o input do filtro**, definir um **ngModel** e chamar a funcao de filtrar no **ngModelChange**.

Exemplo:

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="filtro" (ngModelChange)='filtrar(filtro)'>
```

E adicione a variavel no seu arquivo .ts

```
filtro: string = "";
```

E logo apos voce pegar os dados da API, adicione esses dados na variavel planilha e chame a funcao **filtrar** passando o filtro como parametro.

Arquivo .ts

```
this.filtrar(this.filtro);
```

Comment: Consegui filtrar, porém, como faço para a exibição ir mudando de acordo com o json retornado? Estou com problemas em encaixá-lo na minha chamada assincrona. Muito obrigado!

Comment: @FrancoGenaro editei a resposta e adicionei essa resolucao pelo que entendi da sua pergunta.

Comment: @Gabriel Ferreira, adicionei uma edição, acho que me expressei mal. Já está tudo rolando de acordo exceto a animação, estou com muita dificuldade para achar conteúdo a respeito disso. Tentei seu código mas me trouxe um erro: _Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input'. ("<div>
        <input type="text" [ERROR ->][(ngModel)]="filtro" (ngModelChange)='filtrar(filtro)'>
<table class="table table-striped">_

Comment: @FrancoGenaro essa resposta deve te ajudar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38892771/cant-bind-to-ngmodel-since-it-isnt-a-known-property-of-input

Comment: Não muito ;( não tem nenhum form nesta página e nada que se comporte como um form que seria a dúvida do link. Precisaria que minha TR acompanhasse as alterações do meu JSON, provavelmente alguma alteração no ngfor...

Comment: Digo na questão do erro do ngModel, o que falta é apenas um import no seu app.component.ts. No link que te passei ele fala isso. De resto é só seguir o que te passei que provavelmente funcionará.

Answer (score 0):

Complementando a resposta do @Gabryel, que estava correta, na implementação faltou apenas aplicar este filtro na variável "Planilha" e não na "Planilha Filter", afinal, todo meu HTML estava voltado para "Planilha".

Segue o código do meu filtro:

```
filtrar(value: string) {
      this.planilha = this.planilhaFilter
    if(!value) {
       this.planilha = this.planilha;
    } else {
      this.planilha = this.planilha.filter(x => 
         x.ATENDIMENTO.trim().toLowerCase().includes(value.trim().toLowerCase())
      );
    }
 }
```

Para quem for aplicar, a linha em que coloco  this.planilha = this.planilhaFilter, eu uso a variável "planilhaFilter" como assegurador do meu valor total, assim, não preciso mandar mais requests ao meu banco, se você não fizer desta forma, a variável vai  decrescendo a cada filtro aplicado, até nenhum retorno.